# How to find a list of available Zones (Sharepoint 2013) page layout

Tags: web-part

I have the following WebpartZones available in a template I am working with:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 1" ID="Header"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 6" ID="TopRightRow"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 5" ID="TopLeftRow"/>


<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 2" ID="CenterLeftColumn"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 4" ID="CenterRightColumn"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 3" ID="CenterColumn"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Footer" ID="Footer"/>
```

I want a few more - if i try and duplicate these I get the following dialogue and the page fails to load:

> “Sorry, something went wrong The ID 'CenterRightColumn' is already
>   used by another control.”

Is there a list available or an area within the admin I can locate to gain a full list of available Zones so i can extend my template

Thanks in advance and Happy Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the **webpart zone ID is duplicated**. So, you can name it anything that is unique and makes sense to you and according to your organisations' naming conventions if applicable and then customize your page layout accordingly as below:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 1" ID="Header"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 6" ID="TopRightRow"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 5" ID="TopLeftRow"/>


<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 2" ID="CenterLeftColumn"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 4" ID="CenterRightColumn"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="CenterRightColumn1" ID="CenterRightColumn1"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="CenterRightColumn2" ID="CenterRightColumn2"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="CenterRightColumn3" ID="CenterRightColumn3"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 3" ID="CenterColumn"/>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Test zone" ID="TestZone"/>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Footer" ID="Footer"/>
```

So bottomline, ensure that Webpart Zone ID is unique and you are good to go.

For a list of names not exhaustive, you can refer below link:

[SharePoint Web Part Zone Resources File](http://sp-thornet.blogspot.in/2012/12/sharepoint-web-part-zone-resources-file.html)